# Create Login using SQL with variables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, loops, authentication

I am attempting to create a login loop that grabs the first and last names from my Administrators table and creates a login and user by combining the FirstName and LastName columns. These users will also be assigned to the OrderEntry role.

```
DECLARE Admin_Cursor CURSOR
DYNAMIC
FOR
SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Administrators;
DECLARE @First varchar(50), @Last varchar(50);
DECLARE @initLog varchar(MAX);
OPEN Admin_Cursor
FETCH FIRST FROM Admin_Cursor;
   BEGIN
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    SET @initLog = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + @First + @Last + 
    ' WITH PASSWORD = '+'''temp'''+'MUST_CHANGE, DEFAULT_DATABASE = MyGuitarShop;
    CREATE USER ' + @First + @Last +
    ' ALTER ROLE OrderEntry ADD MEMBER ' + @First + @Last + ';'
    EXEC(@initLog)
    FETCH NEXT FROM Admin_Cursor;
   END
CLOSE Admin_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE Admin_Cursor;
```

I've tried to look up the different reasons this may not be working, but I cannot determine what it is. I've tried changing my FETCH methods (doing FETCH FIRST and just FETCH FROM) but nothing is working. I am not getting an error message, but the loop continues to work and won't continue passed the first row, and does not create a login or user (obviously) for the first row. Can anyone see an error in my code? Thank you in advance for all of your help!

Comment: Updated. It's Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2008.

Comment: (SSMS is irrelevant, mostly - that's just the client used to write the SQL Server queries in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

A `while` statement repeats the statement below it.  That can be a single statement, or a block of statements enclosed in `begin ... end`.

Now your `while` statement is followed by a `set` statement.  So the `set` statement is the one that repeats.  And `set` doesn't do much without `exec`.

Comment: I thought the loop would do all of the below statements until ended? At any rate, putting my `SET` statement above the loop does not change the outcome :(

Comment: Hint: move `begin` below `while`

Comment: Well, it now selects correctly! Thank you! :) I'm thinking there is something wrong with my `EXEC` statement. I just put a `PRINT 'TEST'` in the loop and that works, but the logins and users aren't created. Baffling!

Comment: Replace `exec` with `print`, run one of the printed queries manually, and check the error message.  I can imagine you need an extra space before `MUST_CHANGE`, for example.

Comment: Good idea. I now see that it is printing out 2 spaces "  ", so it seems to be my `SET` that is out of whack. That's a good start at least!